# numpy arrays from dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I am trying to convert a dictionary like this:

```
  dicta = {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6,7,8], 'c':[9,10], 'd':[11,12,13,14], 'e':[15,16]}
```

into arrays (one for each key,value):

```
  a=([1 ,2 ,3])
  b=([4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
  c=([9, 10])
  d=([11, 12, 13, 14])
  e=([15, 16])
```

The dictionary may have more or less than 5 key,value and the number of values for each key can be different from this example.

Any suggestion?

Many thanks,

eg

I have tried various loops but did not work, and I could not find anything that solve the problem.

Comment: It seems that you want to do this to access the arrays later like `print(a)` when you want to do some operations on it. What is wrong with just always calling `dicta["a"]` whenever you want to operate on a specific array? However, if it needs be Numpy arrays you can do `dct = {key: np.array(val) for key, val in dicta.items()}`, which still keeps it in a dict though.

Comment: dicta comes from a json file created by an application. The keys represent the names of the services being evaluated by the application and the values are the related measurements. I need to separate the key/value pairs in different arrays as I will have to use them in various statistical analysis and having the arrays with the same names of the keys will help identifying each different service.

Comment: An experienced python user would be just as happy using `stats_func(dicta['b'])` as `stats_func(b)`.  Creating `b=dicta[b]` does not improve the functionality of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the tolist() function as below:

```
import numpy as np

dicta = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 'c': [9, 10], 'd': [11, 12, 13, 14], 'e': [15, 16]}

for key, value in dicta.items():
    exec(f"{key} = np.array({value}).tolist()")
    print(f"{key} = {eval(key)}")
```

Comment: Many thansk for all the answers.

Answer (score 2):

while you could use exec or eval (as another answer suggest you) it is highly discouraged to do such a thing, both for the inherent dangers of these functions which execute arbitrary code, and because you will lose static analysis capabilities.

Also using vars() etc, would be discourage for readability and static analysis

If you need to access to the elements of the dictionary you can always do it using dicta['a'] and if you need to convert to an array it use:

```
import numpy as np
dct = {key: np.array(val) for key, val in dicta.items()}
```

As @juanpethes pointed out in a comment (which is by far the best solution in my opinion).

For me is hard to imagine a use-case where you really need to name the variables and extract them from the dictionary dynamically, but maybe you can clarify this point and we may find a more appropriate solution.